# propagate new default value to old Django objects

Tags: django, model, default, django-south, database-migration

I just added a default value to one of the fields of one of the models in my Django site. All objects of this type that existed before I set the default have a null value for this field. I would like the new default value that I just set to be propagated backwards onto all of the objects that already existed before I set the default value. How can I do this?

Comment: thanks to all the daniel rose*'s out there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run an update query:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(myfield__isnull=True).update(myfield=new_value)
```

Comment: I solved my problem with a very similar line of code: `orm['main.mymodel'].objects.filter(myfield__isnull=True).update(myfield=0)`. I placed the line in the forwards method of one of my migration scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do a Schemamigration using [South](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html). It's quite easy, just follow the tutorial on their documentation. If you remove `null=True, blank=True` from the field, it will ask you what you want null/blank fields to be, and you can enter your default.

Comment: I removed `null=True, blank=True` and ran `python manage.py schemamigration main --auto` followed by `python manage.py migrate main`. It produced the following error: `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: _south_new_main_network.panel_image_file_id may not be NULL` instead of asking me about my null/blank fields. Please advise.